# In a 3 variables graph, one variable stays at 0 even though its values aren't 0

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make a 3-variables graph with Hours as the absciss, Light Intensity as the left ordinate and Water Temperature as the right ordinate.

I don't know why Light Intensity is fine, but Water Temperature is just a straight line (in orange) on the absciss instead of adjusting to the ordinate on the right.

Here is an image:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: What type of chart do you have? What happens if you make a chart with just the water temp?

Comment: I just put text and numbers under it. The same thing happens when I make it into a board.Here's what happens if it's only hour and water temp: https://i.imgur.com/poyNehr.png

Comment: assuming your water values start in C3, use the following formula `=ISNUMBER(C3)`. You are looking for a value of true. If you get a value of FALSE it means you have numbers that are entered as text. Numbers as text will be treated at 0

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change it, water temp is using the left (primary) y-axis. The numbers are so small, that the graph seems to be a straight line (the first tick is 5000, so 20 will be less than a pixel = invisible).

Select the water graph, and change it to use the secondary Y-axis.